# MySQL and PHP counting the minutes and hours from registration date?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I count the minutes and hours since a member registered from there registration date that is stored in my MySQL database as datetime using PHP & MySQL.

Here is what I have so far.

```
date('F j, Y g:i:s A', strtotime($row['rdate']))
```

Comment: just hours and minutes or everything? like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260064/php-convert-html-formatted-date/260199#260199

Comment: That seems it will work just as good but hours and minutes maybe days?

Answer (score 2):

The cleanest answer is to ask the database SQL parser to do it.

```
SELECT
   DATEDIFF(NOW(), registered_date) AS days_since_registration,
   TIMEDIFF(NOW(), registered_date) AS hours_since_registration
FROM users;
```

That's assuming the column `registered_date` is of format `DATETIME`.

BTW, it's also better to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` on the query rather than using `strftime()` as MySQL has an internal format for the datetime and can convert it to a unix time without guessing. `strftime()` is unlikely to have problems but does have to parse a date format and that involves guessing.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you almost had it, this gives the basic principle:

```
$seconds = time() - strtotime( $row['rdate'] );
$minutes = $seconds / 60;
$hours = $seconds / 3600;
$days = $seconds / 86400;
$weeks = $seconds / 604800;
```

Answer (score 0):

time ago in words taken from examples on here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

is that what you want

example output 1 hour 3 minutes ago

```
public static function timeAgo($date){
            if(empty($date)) {
                return "No date provided";
            }

            if( Settings::read( 'localize') ){
                $periods = array("{{second}}", "{{minute}}", "{{hour}}", "{{day}}", "{{week}}", "{{month}}", "{{year}}", "{{decade}}");
            }else{
                $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
            }
            $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");

            $now = time();

            strtotime($date);   

            //

            // check validity of date
            if(empty($unix_date)) {   
                return "Bad date";
            }

            // is it future date or past date
            if($now > $unix_date) {   
                $difference     = $now - $unix_date;
                $tense         = "ago";

            } else {
                $difference     = $unix_date - $now;
                $tense         = "from now";
            }

            for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
                $difference /= $lengths[$j];
            }

            $difference = round($difference);

            if($difference != 1) {
                $periods[$j].= "s";
            }

            return "$difference $periods[$j] {$tense}";
        }
```