# Format Date and text

Tags: date, format, date-format, yahoo-pipes, pubdate

I need to format the pubDate to  example :

> 2 hours ago,   2 days ago or   20 hours ago ....

while keeping the original date of the feed cause i tried to format before and i get all my feeds same pubDate the one i set in Date format and the date builder. How can i solve this issue ?

As well i tried to format the text of my pubdate and (Read full article ) when i run pipe its perfect but in pipe output and when i call the rss file from my website i always get the format as code.

You help will be greatly appreciated...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Convert HTML Formatted Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/260064/php-convert-html-formatted-date)

Comment: Where are these php assumptions coming from? He only mentions yahoo pipes.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowDate($date) // $date -->  time(); value
{
$stf = 0;
$cur_time = time();
$diff = $cur_time - $date;
$phrase = array('second','minute','hour','day','week','month','year','decade');
$length = array(1,60,3600,86400,604800,2630880,31570560,315705600);

for($i =sizeof($length)-1; ($i >=0)&amp;&amp;(($no =  $diff/$length[$i])< =1); $i--); if($i < 0) $i=0; $_time = $cur_time  -($diff%$length[$i]);
$no = floor($no); if($no <> 1) $phrase[$i] .='s'; $value=sprintf("%d %s ",$no,$phrase[$i]);

if(($stf == 1)&amp;&amp;($i >= 1)&amp;&amp;(($cur_tm-$_time) > 0)) $value .= time_ago($_time);

return $value.' ago ';
}
```

You need to pass the date within that and you can get the desire format.

This is php function that will convert the time as a 2 hours ago and so on...

For more further function you can check this link [Date time formate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/260064/1035257)